# How can I increase the mouse sensitivity of Magic Mouse?

Tags: macos, mouse

I have a MacBook Pro, running Snow Leopard and I'm using a Magic Mouse which connects through Bluetooth.

While I like the mouse, it's way too slow for my taste. Moving the mouse cursor takes ages. On my Windows PC I'm using a Logitech G9 and in Control Panel of Windows I have set Pointer Speed to maximum with the '[Enhance Pointer Precision](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/mouse-ballistics.html)' box checked.

On OS X I have set the speed set to maximum as well, but it's still way to slow. I'm used to move the pointer from from egde of the screen to another one with minimal wrist movement.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are 5 Mac utilities that alter the mouse acceleration curve, speeds, and/or add features to mice in OS X:

[USB Overdrive](http://www.usboverdrive.com/)

**$20** (Shareware; Free unlimited, fully functional trial)

> USB Overdrive is a popular program
>   that works with just about any USB or
>   Bluetooth input device. It allows
>   users to customize mouse acceleration,
>   scrolling, clicking, and more. You can
>   even configure per-application
>   settings. A new version that supports
>   Multi-Touch in Apple’s Magic Mouse is
>   in development and expected soon.

Version 3.0.1 compatible with 10.4, 10.5, or 10.6

[SteerMouse](http://plentycom.jp/en/steermouse)

**$20** (Shareware; Free 30 day trial)

> Aside from mouse acceleration,
>   SteerMouse offers a ton of other
>   advanced features. Configure up to 16
>   buttons, modify scroll wheels/balls,
>   and set the cursor to automatically
>   move to a specific location on the
>   screen when a window is activated.
>   Support for the Apple Magic Mouse is
>   pending.

Version 4.0.1 compatible with 10.4, 10.5, or 10.6

[MouseZoom](http://benh57.com/mousezoom.html)

**Free**

> While MouseZoom does not alter the
>   acceleration curve itself, it does let
>   users bump tracking speeds beyond
>   those available in System Preferences.
>   An ideal solution? No, but it’s a free
>   alternative that helps ease the pain.

Version 2.2 compatible with 10.1, 10.2, 10.4, 10.4, or 10.5

[Mouse Acceleration](http://triq.net/software/mouse-acceleration-preference-pane-mac-os-x)

**Free**

> This Preference Pane is based on
>   Richard Bentley’s MouseFix – a
>   non-user-friendly command line
>   utility. This version, however, makes
>   it easy to increase mouse precision
>   and speed up mouse movement with
>   visual aids.

Version 1.0 compatible with 10.4 or 10.5

[BetterTouchTool](http://blog.boastr.net/)

**Free**

> This is a brand new piece of software
>   that just came to be within the past
>   couple weeks. It’s in beta and still
>   buggy, but it packs some nice features
>   and is in active development. I can’t
>   say for sure whether it customizes OS
>   X’s acceleration curve or just
>   supercharges the maximum tracking
>   speed. The real reason to give it a
>   shot, though, is if you have a Magic
>   Mouse or MacBook that supports
>   Multi-Touch gestures. BetterTouchTool
>   lets users assign specific actions to
>   advanced finger gestures and can
>   simulate a middle-click. It can even
>   bring the Mighty Mouse’s Exposé
>   functionality to the Magic Mouse.

Compatible with 10.6

[ControllerMate](http://orderedbytes.com/controllermate/)

**$15**

> ControllerMate is a controller
>   programming tool that allows you to
>   customize the behavior of your HID
>   devices — keyboards, keypads, mice,
>   trackballs, joysticks, gamepads,
>   throttles, among others.
>   ControllerMate’s philosophy is to be
>   as flexible as possible, to provide a
>   set of basic programming tools, and to
>   allow the user to combine those tools
>   in an endless variety of ways.

**SOURCE**: This was posted on Nov 24th, 2009 at [MacYourself.com](http://www.macyourself.com/2009/11/24/5-mac-mouse-related-utilities-that-alter-acceleration-add-features/). Some utilities are probably updated now. I’ve used USB Overdrive with certain success.

Comment: Just to add now that Lion is out: Apple finally fixed this, the mouse sensitivity in Lion is much better.

Comment: This is a great answer, but for me - none of the free software was able to make the mouse *feel* right. Upgrading from Snow Leopard to Lion, however - did the trick.

Comment: BetterTouchTool is no longer free software, it is "name your price"-software with a minimum fee (check pricing).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Better Touch tool.  Works perfect.

Comment: Can you please specify your answer a bit more?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  We like answers to be more than just a single line.  Ideally, you want to explain why your answer is *right."  It also helps to provide links, citations, and/or screen shots.  Please review our help section [How to Answer](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on writing good answers to questions

Comment: As of macOS Sierra, BetterTouchTool cannot increase mouse speed beyond the maximum in System Preferences, due to some technical limitation in Sierra.